# Show error messages in UIAlertView by UIAlerView+AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

There is a categroy UIAlertView+AFNetworking.h ship with AFNetworking 2.0. And I use it to show error messages in my App like this:

```
[UIAlertView showAlertViewForTaskWithErrorOnCompletion:task delegate:nil]
```

But I want to add some other messages in the message of UIAlertView.

i.e.:

> StatusCode: 422
>
> JSON Data: {"errors":{"detail":"Wrong password"}}

How to get "Wrong password" and show in a UIAlertView by the functions in UIAlertView+AFNetworking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIAlertView+AFNetworking` category uses error messages from *NSError* – `localizedDescription`, `localizedRecoverySuggestion` and `localizedFailureReason`. AFNetworking generates *NSError* on failure, however, you must write your own *responseSerializer* to set your custom error messages there.

This topic has been thoroughly discussed [on GitHub](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1397) and I use solution based *@camdez*'s code snippet.

My error response messages from API looks like this:

```
{ error: { message: "This username already exists" } }
```

Now, I've subclassed AFJSONResponseSerializer and when an error occurs, I save the error message to the *NSError* instance.

**CustomResponseSerializer.h**

```
@interface CustomResponseSerializer : AFJSONResponseSerializer

@end
```

**CustomResponseSerializer.m**

```
@implementation CustomResponseSerializer

- (id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                           data:(NSData *)data
                          error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    id JSONObject = [super responseObjectForResponse:response data:data error:error]; // may mutate `error`

    if (*error && [JSONObject objectForKey:@"error"]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *mutableUserInfo = [(*error).userInfo mutableCopy];

        mutableUserInfo[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = [[JSONObject objectForKey:@"error"] objectForKey:@"message"];

        NSError *newError = [NSError errorWithDomain:(*error).domain code:(*error).code userInfo:[mutableUserInfo copy]];
        (*error) = newError;
    }

    return JSONObject;
}

@end
```

Finally, you need to set appropriate *responseSerializer* on `AFHTTPSessionManager` (or `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` if you use NSURLConnection API) instance. If you subclass this class as I do, you can simply do it in your init method by following:

```
self.responseSerializer = [CustomResponseSerializer serializer];
```